# How to structure a lot of workplace trainings into a resume?

Tags: resume, work-experience, training

I am a registered nurse and took many workplace trainings in hospitals during my career (still unfinished). 
When I put them on the resume, people have recommended that I add them in the "Experience" section, but there are so many (6 in Spain and 4 in Finland) and with a short duration (three weeks on average).
I've structured each one this way:

- Title *Registered Nurse (workplace training)*
- Hospital name
- Location
- Dates
- Description

I think it's too pretentious because I have no on the job experience yet and swells the CV too much.

- Are the workplace trainings well placed?
- Should I put them all together in one paragraph?
- What would be the best way to structure a CV in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of listing them down with a newline for every point you could structure it like a bibliography, something like: Hospital name - Location - Year - Duration. You could add a newline after each one with a short description if you want. Just a thought here. Have you asked other nurses how they deal with this issue?

Comment: Ok, but should I place them in "experience" or in "education"? Thank you! :)

Comment: Isn't this type of experience expected by those in your industry? You can't be the first nurse to get significant areas of training before your first job.

Answer (score 2):

I'd put your courses in the SKILLS SET section of your reume, and write them up as follows:

**SKILLS SET**

- Took courses in A, B, C (Barcelona Hospital, Spain) and D, E, F Helsinki Hopital, Finland) and put the knowledge and training acquired to immediate use.
- Acquired a degree of proficiency in everyday Spanish and Finnish.

I'd be kind of reluctant to put your training under EDUCATION - lots of people get educated in something and don't do much with their education.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would all depend on how your resume is laid out. But, I would suggest adding a "Workplace Training" section on your resume.

Were they ones in Spain and Finland at the same hospitals? If so, group them under that heading under the hospital name, and put the dates down for each one and give a brief description of the over all work out did.

I feel you don't want this section to bloat out your resume. You want to just give a nice overview says that you've done a lot of training. If a potential employer is interested in it, they will ask you in your interview.

Answer (score 0):

### Education vs. Experience

- if you are working and received on the job training, it's fine to put it in experience.
- if you got the training off hours, unpaid, or as a very optional enhancement to your work, then put it in the education section.
- if the training can be described in an industry standard qualification - put it in the education section.

This sounds more like on the job training, so I'd include it as experience unless the education is preparing you for a degree or certification - in which case "courses preparing for XYZ" can go in education.

### On the Job Education

I don't expect that an experience section will be filled with training information.  If that's what's happening, I think you need a way to highlight the work that you've done so that the education part doesn't overwhelm the section.

With that said, different industries are different.  As a manager of engineers, I don't expect that normal training like bootcamps, or conferences (1-2 weeks per experience) will even be a part of the experience section... because they are normal part of the work, and not as important to me as the reader as the work that the person accomplished.

In a role where having had the training is an important precursor to being able to perform certain tasks (as I'm betting it is true in the health fields), I would focus on making clear what the tasks you can do are and what you are qualified for now that you've had the training.

### Summarizing and Bulleting

When ever you have a long list, it's nice to provide a bulleted list.  It saves the reader trying to parse a long paragraph, and shows the reader that the items in the list are comparable.

Organize the list hierarchically, and focus the eye so that every separate thought gets a new line and/or an indent.

The presentation you suggested is very flat and very long - it has 5 bullets for 1 idea.  I'd structure it this way:

- **Type of Training** - *hospital & location - date* - description

That lets the reader read from most important to most detailed.  The italics focus on the eye first on the summary, then on some relevant details, then on the description.

Know your field and your audience - if the training is highly variable based on the place that gave it, then list these details, but if you got training that would be largely the same regardless of hospital, it's OK to omit details.

Also - if end up placing the training information in your experience section, realize that you've already given a detail about the hospital and location, as I suspect you'll have a format like this:

**Hospital, Location, Dates, Title**

- work you did, responsibilities, accomplishments
- *Training*:

  - training 1
  - training 2

At which point you can skip repeating the hospital and location over and over, and you may even skip the dates of the training if it really doesn't matter what month you did it... (if, for example, the training is less relevant when it's three years old, keep the dates, but if it doesn't matter for the viability of your qualification, leave it off).

Answer (score 0):

As a registered nurse, I will just add - if it's a course/workshop that helped to improve a required skill (ie, using a pain pump, this is part of the job and I would not add this as a separate skill. Instead, I would just emphasize this skill under your job description for that particular unit/hospital. For example - Spanish hospital, Palliative care unit (dates employed) bullet #1: supported palliative care patients with pain management using subcutaneous injections, oral medications, pain pumps etc. Obviously, this is a very basic example and I hope you get the gist of it.

The other section that I have on my resume is titled professional development. Under this heading I simply put bullet points with the title of the course (giving credit to whom ever offered the course and the year it was taken). For example: Finland Hospital Association wound care course - 2013. No descriptions, if it's pertinent to the job, the interviewing manager will know what it is, if not, no matter it just proves on-going professional development. Otherwise, I leave it up to being asked or actually speaking about the courses during an interview. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I would arrange them as a list, with the years and location in parenthesis:

Course of Something (2009, Finland), Another course (2010, Finland), A different course (2012, Spain), More coursework (2012, Spain), Training course (2013, Kyrgystan), Even more (2014, Tasmania)

Comment: Thanks! But I think the activities realized are interesting to display too. What if i put one parragraph titled 'Registered Nurse (workplace training)' and put all them with the structure: hospital, dates, description ?